# Accessing members of a struct inside of another struct's array

Tags: c, data-structures

-- student learning C here --

I've been instructed to create a "[StructureType] that is a collection structure which contains a primitive (regular) array of
[OtherStructureType] pointers." Also, "the [StructureType] will be filled with 10 dynamically allocated [OtherStructureType] structures."

I'm having a hard time understanding this conceptually and in a practical sense. Here's my stab at it. Please correct me where needed...

1.) If we use malloc() to dynamically allocate an instance of OtherStructureType, it would be a pointer:

```
typedef struct{
    int age;
} OtherStructureType;

OtherStructureType * Person = malloc(1 * sizeof(OtherStructureType))
```

2.) If an instance of StructureType has an array member, then we can put this pointer in that array:

```
typedef struct{
    int array[n];
} StructureType;

StructureType Collection;

Collection.array = Person;
```

3.) If 1 & 2 is correct, how then would we access Person's age? Like this?

```
StructureType* ptr;
ptr = Collection;
ptr->array[i].age;
```

Edit1: I said Instance.array = Person; when I should have wrote Collection.array = Person;
Edit2: clarity between array in Q2 and Q3

Comment: It would be best if you showed your interpretation of how `StructureType` and `OtherStructureType` are defined, and created an MCVE ([MCVE]) which shows your best effort at working code and explains why what you see isn't what you want to see.  A1: That would work.  A2: You need an array of pointers to `OtherStructureType`, so why are you using an array of `int` (and what's `n`)?   A3: if you had `StructureType *ptr = &Collection;`, then `ptr->array[n].age` would access an age element if `n` is under control (within bounds of the array) — but the `n` here must be different from the `n` in A2.

Comment: Oh, in A2, you have `Instance.array = Person;` — that won't work.  `Instance.array` is an array; you can't assign to arrays like that.  It's a bit hard to know how to correct it since neither `Instance` isn't defined, but presumably `Person` is from Q1.  What should work is `Collection.array[0] = Person;`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your help! I think your response to A2 shows me that I'm misunderstanding what "array of pointers to OtherStructureType" means. Could you clarify?

Comment: I think you should have something like: `enum { N = 10 }; typedef struct { int num_ptrs; OtherStructureType *array[N]; } StructureType;` — where `N` is a constant (could be `#define N 10`, and you'd probably choose a better name).  The `num_ptrs` element would allow you to keep track of how many of the elements of the `array` element hold a valid pointer.  Accessing invalid pointers is a recipe for madness or crashes, so you need to know how many are valid (with the assumption that it is elements 0..`num_ptrs-1` that are valid if `num_ptrs > 0`).

Comment: Incidentally, as a matter of style, it might be best to keep initial capitals for types, with lower-case for variables (and structure elements, and maybe functions too), and upper-case for constants . Certainly, it is a good idea to keep the names separated.   Function names might be in `CamelCase()` or `camelCase()`.  All sorts of systems have been used, but `StructureType Collection` is a little disconcerting, for example — `StructureType collection` would be more orthodox.  Not the biggest problem you've got at the moment, but keep it in mind.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler noted! I'll continue to work on it... Ideally I would make a MCVE but I can't at the moment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Assignment

> - Create a "[StructureType] that is a collection structure which contains a primitive (regular) array of [OtherStructureType] pointers."
> - Also, "the [StructureType] will be filled with 10 dynamically allocated [OtherStructureType] structures."

Partial answer (material from question):

> ```
> typedef struct
> {
>     int age;
> } OtherStructureType;
>
> OtherStructureType *person = malloc(1 * sizeof(OtherStructureType));
> ```

This much of the code is fine (as long as the assignment is inside a function).  I changed `Person` to `person` for stylistic reasons (it is easier to distinguish types and variables if you don't start them all with capital letters).

> 2. If an instance of StructureType has an array member, then …

This section of the question is essentially completely incorrect.  You have an array of integers, not an array of pointers to `OtherStructureType`.  And it isn't clear what `n` is defined as.  To be used in a structure definition, it must be a constant, and constants are conventionally written in all upper-case letters (with numbers and underscores as needed).  Generally, a name like this should be longer than just `N` (perhaps `NUM_OTHERS`), but it will do for this example.  Also, I generally use a tag for the structure as well as using a `typedef`, but I've left the structures tagless.

```
enum { N = 10 };
typedef struct
{
    OtherStructureType *array[N];
} StructureType;

StructureType collection;

collection.array[0] = person;
```

This would work as long as the assignment is inside a function.

> 3.How then would we access Person's age? …

```
StructureType *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
OtherStructureType *other = malloc(sizeof(*other));
ptr->array[0] = other;
ptr->array[0]->age = 21;
```

These are approximately the minimum changes that will work (see `nest31.c` below for an MCVE).

#### More changes

I think you should have something like:

```
enum { N = 10 };
typedef struct StructureType
{
    int num_ptrs;
    OtherStructureType *array[N];
} StructureType;
```

The `num_ptrs` element allows you to keep track of how many of the elements of the array element hold a valid pointer. Accessing invalid pointers is a recipe for madness or crashes, so you need to know how many are valid (with the assumption that it is elements 0..`num_ptrs-1` that are valid if `num_ptrs > 0`).  This applies if you allocate pointed at `OtherStructureType` values at different times.

See `nest53.c` below for an MCVE.

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768854/accessing-members-of-a-struct-inside-of-another-structs-array/52769096?noredirect=1#comment92461746_52769096), [nielan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10256042/nielan) asks:

> If we want to have 10 people, instead of doing each one individually can we dynamically allocate an array instance of StructureType.

I [responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768854/accessing-members-of-a-struct-inside-of-another-structs-array/52769096?noredirect=1#comment92461880_52769096):

Yes, you can do it, though you'd probably have:

```
typedef struct
{
    int num_ptrs;
    int num_used;
    OtherStructureType *people;
} StructureType;
```

and you could then use:

```
StructureType st;
st.num_ptrs = 10;
st.num_used = 0;
st.people = malloc(st.num_ptrs * sizeof(st.people[0]));
```

(remembering to check that the allocation succeeded). Or:

```
StructureType *stp = malloc(sizeof(*stp));
stp->num_ptrs = 10;
stp->num_used = 0;
stp->people = malloc(stp->num_ptrs * sizeof(stp->people[0]));
```

There are variants where you initialize `st` instead of doing assignments after defining it, as long as you're inside a function when defining the variable.  For example:

```
StructureType st = { .num_ptrs = 10, .num_used = 0,
                     .people = malloc(st.num_ptrs * sizeof(st.people[0]))
                   };
```

You still need to check that the memory allocation was successful.  Now you can use notations such as:

```
st.people[0].age = 21;
```

instead of using:

```
st.people[0]->age = 21;
```

Note that there's one less pointer access in the first of these two expressions, so the access is (marginally!) more efficient.

See `nest73.c` below for an MCVE.

---

#### `nest31.c`

```
/* SO 5276-8854 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int age;
} OtherStructureType;

enum { N = 10 };
typedef struct
{
    OtherStructureType *array[N];
} StructureType;

int main(void)
{
    OtherStructureType *person = malloc(1 * sizeof(OtherStructureType));
    StructureType collection;

    collection.array[0] = person;
    collection.array[0]->age = 23;
    printf("Age: %d\n", collection.array[0]->age);

    StructureType *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    OtherStructureType *other = malloc(sizeof(*other));
    ptr->array[0] = other;
    ptr->array[0]->age = 21;
    printf("Age: %d\n", ptr->array[0]->age);

    free(ptr);
    free(other);
    free(person);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output from `nest31`

```
Age: 23
Age: 21
```

#### `nest53.c`

```
/* SO 5276-8854 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int age;
} OtherStructureType;

enum { N = 10 };
typedef struct StructureType
{
    int num_ptrs;
    OtherStructureType *array[N];
} StructureType;

int main(void)
{
    OtherStructureType *person = malloc(1 * sizeof(OtherStructureType));
    StructureType collection = { 0, { 0 } };

    collection.array[0] = person;
    collection.num_ptrs = 1;
    collection.array[0]->age = 23;
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.num_ptrs; i++)
        printf("Age %d: %d\n", i, collection.array[i]->age);

    StructureType *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    OtherStructureType *other = malloc(sizeof(*other));
    ptr->num_ptrs = 1;
    ptr->array[0] = other;
    ptr->array[0]->age = 21;
    for (int i = 0; i < ptr->num_ptrs; i++)
        printf("Age %d: %d\n", i, ptr->array[i]->age);

    free(ptr);
    free(other);
    free(person);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output from `nest53`

```
Age 0: 23
Age 0: 21
```

#### `nest73.c`

```
/* SO 5276-8854 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int age;
} OtherStructureType;

typedef struct
{
    int num_ptrs;
    int num_used;
    OtherStructureType *people;
} StructureType;

int main(void)
{

    StructureType st;
    st.num_ptrs = 10;
    st.people = malloc(st.num_ptrs * sizeof(st.people[0]));
    st.people[0].age = 21;
    st.people[1].age = 23;
    st.people[2].age = 19;
    st.num_used = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < st.num_used; i++)
        printf("Age %d: %d\n", i, st.people[i].age);

    StructureType *stp = malloc(sizeof(*stp));
    stp->num_ptrs = 10;
    stp->people = malloc(stp->num_ptrs * sizeof(stp->people[0]));
    stp->people[0].age = 51;
    stp->people[1].age = 49;
    stp->people[2].age = 37;
    stp->num_used = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < stp->num_used; i++)
        printf("Age %d: %d\n", i, stp->people[i].age);

    free(st.people);
    free(stp->people);
    free(stp);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output from `nest73`

```
Age 0: 21
Age 1: 23
Age 2: 19
Age 0: 51
Age 1: 49
Age 2: 37
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course your code is invalid and will not even compile

```
#define NPEOPLE 10

typedef struct{
    int age;
} OtherStructureType;

typedef struct{
    OtherStructureType *ost;
} StructureType;


OtherStructureType * Person = malloc(1 * sizeof(*Person));
StructureType People;

People.ost = malloc(NPEOPLE * sizeof(People.ost));

Person -> age = 20;

People.ost[0] = Person;


/*Access*/

int age = People.ost[0] -> age; 

/* Or */

StructureType *People1 = malloc(sizeof(*People1));

People1 -> ost = malloc(NPEOPLE * sizeof(People1 ->ost));

Person -> age = 20;

People1 -> ost[0] = Person;

/*Access*/

int age = People1 -> ost[0] -> age;
```

---

```
/* or */

typedef struct{
    OtherStructureType *ost[NPEOPLE];
} StructureType;

StructureType *People2 = malloc(sizeof(*People2));

Person -> age = 20;

People2 -> ost[0] = Person;

/*Access*/

int age = People1 -> ost[0] -> age;
```

Comment: The question says _"[StructureType] that is a collection structure which contains a primitive (regular) array of [OtherStructureType] pointers."_ . Your `StructureType` does not match that, for no explained reason.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler added the array version as well

Comment: I do not like seeing spaces around the dot `.` or arrow `->` operators.  They bind very tightly; no space is appropriate.

Comment: If we want to have 10 people, instead of doing each one individually can we dynamically allocate an array instance of StructureType...

`StructureType *People[n] = malloc(sizeof(*People[n]));`

Comment: @nielan: Yes, you can do it, though you'd probably have `typedef struct { int num_ptrs; int num_used; OtherStructureType *people; } StructureType;` and you could then use: `StructureType st; st.num_ptrs = 10; st.num_used = 0; st.people = malloc(st.num_ptrs * sizeof(st.people[0]));` (remembering to check that the allocation succeeded).  Or `StructureType *stp = malloc(sizeof(*stp)); stp->num_ptrs = 10; stp->num_used = 0; stp->people = malloc(stp->num_ptrs * sizeof(stp->people[0]));` … etc.  There are variants where you initialize `st` instead of doing assignments after definining it.

Comment: @P__J__ can you please clarify why you declared and initialized `int age` under access?

Comment: @nielan this is just an example and I just assign some variable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I do like `x -> y` but `x.y`. You can of course like something else. I like slim woman - you do not have to :)